# Can't receive text messages or phone calls after last Windows update

Tags: windows-10-mobile

After the last Windows update I had to hard restart my phone and start all over again because it kept restarting over and over. About a week after that my phone was spotty when it came to me receiving text messages and phone calls. Now I only get text messages if I'm calling out and they come all at once. I can call out and text out just not receive. T-Mobile says there's nothing wrong with my line and that it's probably a software issue. Can anybody help me with this? Thank you

Comment: What version of Windows 10 Mobile are you running? Are you enrolled in the Windows Insider programme?

Comment: What device are you using? Which version of the operating system is reported as installed?

Comment: I have no idea which Windows 10 I have. I have an Alcatel Fierce XL. I am signed up for the Insider program... I don't think I am. My phone last updated the middle of November. The more I look into this phone the more I'm finding out that I'm not the only one with this phone issue.

Answer (score 1):

So I went to T mobile and it seems there have been a number of people with my problem. The manager switched out my sim card with a new one and it seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: If this don't help HArd reset maybe is solution